# Get all elements in a div with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to scrape Project Gutenberg.

I am able to use the .getElementsByClassName("chapter") to get the divs that hold the chapters. However, I am unable to get all the elements in that div as a collection that I would then be able to iterate over.

```
Sub getZ()
Dim H As Object, C As New DataObject, stryn&, cptr%, html As New HTMLDocument, p As HTMLHtmlElement, para As Object, i&
Set H = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With H
    .SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
    .SetTimeouts 0, 0, 0, 0
    .Open "GET", "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/8164/8164-h/8164-h.htm", False
    .Send
    .WaitForResponse
End With

html.body.innerHTML = H.ResponseText
Set para = html.getElementsByClassName("chapter").getElementsByTagName("*")

i = 1

For Each p In para
    Worksheets("Output").Range("A" & i & "") = p.innerText
    i = i + 1
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I am getting an error with getElementsByTagName("*") as the object doesn't support that method.

Comment: Please, try `Set para = html.getElementsByClassName("chapter") `. Not need of something else... The object will keep all tags of this Class. Of course, if I correctly understood what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work as html.getElementsByClassName("chapter") gets an Object/DispHTMLElementCollection (like an array), it has not a method getElementsByTagName(). But an Object/HTMLDivElement has it. So this will work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getZ()
Dim H As Object, C As New DataObject, stryn&, cptr%, html As New HTMLDocument, p As HTMLHtmlElement, para As Object, i&
Dim objChapters As Object, objChapter1 As Object

Set H = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With H
    .SetAutoLogonPolicy 0
    .SetTimeouts 0, 0, 0, 0
    .Open "GET", "https://www.gutenberg.org/files/8164/8164-h/8164-h.htm", False
    .Send
    .WaitForResponse
End With

html.Body.innerHTML = H.responseText
'Set para = html.getElementsByClassName("chapter").getElementsByTagName("*")
Set objChapters = html.getElementsByClassName("chapter")

i = 1

For Each objChapter1 In objChapters
  Set para = objChapter1.getElementsByTagName("*")
  For Each p In para
    Worksheets("Output").Range("A" & i & "") = p.innerText
    i = i + 1
  Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'
Set objChapters = Nothing
Set objChapter1 = Nothing
Set para = Nothing
Set p = Nothing
Set html = Nothing
Set H = Nothing

End Sub
```

This gets all child elements of class 'chapter'.

Comment: That's it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner, and faster, would be to combine your requirements (all children of a class) using a css query, and then loop the returned nodeList e.g.

```
With html.querySelectorAll(".chapter > *")
    For i = 0 To .Length - 1
        Worksheets("Output").Range("A" & i + 1) = .Item(i).innerText
    Next
End With
```

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks. It is one of those weird pages where the reference must be held from htmlDocument. Updated.

Comment: Really **weird**, indeed! It maybe requires a different declaration than `Object` and I tried almost everything possible to match, based on Intellisense suggestions, but no chance to find the right declaration. Anyhow, `Object` should work for everything, if an object... Otherwise the `.length` property will rise an error, I think...

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a nodeList which must be declared as Object. There  is the odd occasion with certain types of pages where it returns JScriptTypeInfo but that is where a javascript engine is involved i.e. a browser.